# Fatal Exception: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080137

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, crashlytics

por favor necesito ayuda u orientación de que puede estar provocando este problema que estoy recibiendo a través de Firebase Crashlytics. Pero no veo que esté asociado a uno de los archivos de la aplicación.

```
Alerta de velocidad
ResourcesImpl.java line 239
android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue
```

Seguimiento de pila:

```
Fatal Exception: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080137
       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:239)
       at android.content.res.MiuiResourcesImpl.getValue(MiuiResourcesImpl.java:96)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1445)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.createDrawableIfNeeded(ResourceManagerInternal.java:180)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:145)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:136)
       at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:66)
       at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:505)
       at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.initialize(ActionMenuItemView.java:126)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.bindItemView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:207)
       at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.getItemView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:188)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.getItemView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:193)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.flagActionItems(ActionMenuPresenter.java:469)
       at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.flagActionItems(MenuBuilder.java:1176)
       at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:96)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:226)
       at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchPresenterUpdate(MenuBuilder.java:292)
       at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.onItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:1063)
       at androidx.appcompat.view.menu.MenuBuilder.startDispatchingItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:1090)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1952)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2191)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$2.run(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:276)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8056)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
```

Alguna referencia de que puede estar pasando ?

Answer (score 0):

El error

> Fatal Exception: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException:
> Resource ID

se puede generar por dos causas:

---

Estás llamando `.setText()`, pero estás estableciendo un valor de tipo `Int` como parámetro, la función [setText()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setText(int)) tiene un [constructor el cual puede recibir un valor de tipo `Int` como parámetro](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setText(int)), pero esto le indica que trate de cargar un recurso con este ID, el cual seguramente no existe.
Ejemplo para producir el error:

```
int valor = 12;
...
...
textView.setText(valor);
```

en este caso debes convertir el valor entero a `String` para evitar el error

```
textView.setText(String.valueOf(valor));
```

---

La segunda causa es que tratas de obtener la referencia de una vista y esta no existe en tu layout, o existe, pero no en todos los layout con el mismo nombre.

Debes asegurar que en los layout que contengas en tu proyecto y que sean para diferentes tipos de pantalla o densidad, se tengan definidas las mismas vistas dentro de los mismos.

Por ejemplo, cuando defines dos layout, uno en `/layout` y otro en `/layout-sw720dp`, si la vista a la cual deseas hacer referencia solo existe en el primer layout y no en el segundo, cuando el sistema operativo trate de usar el segundo, no podrá obtener la referencia de la vista y se generaría el error `Resources$NotFoundException`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: gracias @Jorgesys por tu respuesta. Pero el log no me entrega ninguna referencia de donde buscar que se pueda estar provocando esto. En cuanto a los Layout solo tengo una carpeta con ese nombre. En los simuladores y los terminales reales que utilizo para las pruebas no tengo ningún problema. Como se puede saber donde o cuando ocurre esto ?